# How to run QML StateMachine example from Qt's documentation?

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

I'm getting back into Qt lately after a hiatus of several years, and it looks like QML is the "new hotness" these days. In the past, I've managed to get widget-based examples from Qt's documentation to work with relative ease, but... now that I'm trying to learn QML, I'm having trouble closing the gaps in the example code.

Specifically, the docs for [`Qt.QmlStateMachine`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-statemachine-statemachine.html) say:

> The following snippet shows a state machine that will finish when a button is clicked:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQml.StateMachine 1.0 as DSM

Rectangle {
    Button {
        anchors.fill: parent
        id: button
        text: "Finish state"
        DSM.StateMachine {
            id: stateMachine
            initialState: state
            running: true
            DSM.State {
                id: state
                DSM.SignalTransition {
                    targetState: finalState
                    signal: button.clicked
                }
            }
            DSM.FinalState {
                id: finalState
            }
            onFinished: Qt.quit()
        }
    }
}
```

Perhaps I'm completely naive, but I thought I could just create a new *Qt Quick* application in QtCreator and paste the above snippet into `main.qml`. When I do this, though, I'm immediately confronted with an error saying:

```
QQmlApplicationEngine failed to load component
qrc:/main.qml:19 Button is not a type
```

So... I look at the docs for the [QML `Button` type](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-button.html) and notice that it says near the top:

> Import Statement: `import QtQuick.Controls 1.4`

So, I add that to the top of `main.qml` and try to run again. And it 'works', but... there's no main window—or any other visual content whatsoever. Hmm. I guess I can see where that (maybe) makes sense, perhaps I shouldn't have replaced the *entire* contents of `main.qml`? So I decide to try retaining the `Window` component from the original QML supplied by QtCreator, changing my `main.qml` file to look like this:

```
import QtQuick 2.8                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQml.StateMachine 1.0 as DSM

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Rectangle {
        Button {
            anchors.fill: parent
            id: button
            text: "Finish state"
            DSM.StateMachine {
                id: stateMachine
                initialState: state
                running: true
                DSM.State {
                    id: state1
                    DSM.SignalTransition {
                        targetState: finalState
                        signal: button.clicked
                    }
                }
                DSM.FinalState {
                    id: finalState
                }
                onFinished: Qt.quit()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After doing this, I see a main window when I run, but it is *empty*. Um... shouldn't there at least be a *button* in there somewhere?

Anyway, I wasn't smart enough to figure this out after almost 90 minutes of fiddling around. It seems that Qt's documentation authors are assuming a basic level of QML knowledge that I simply don't possess, so I'm unable to 'fill in the blanks'. Which is a real shame, because QML looks *awesome*. And I'm particularly excited to see what I can do with the declarative state machine framework! Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong with this particular example?

(In case it matters, I'm using Qt 5.9.2 with QtCreator 4.4.1...)

**UPDATE**: In his answer, @eyllanesc pointed out a small typo in the second code snippet I posted above.  Where I wrote `id: state1`, it should have been `id: state`.

Comment: What is your question? if your question is: *is there some general strategy I can use to make QML code snippets from Qt's documentation work?*, this is too broad doing it off-topic in SO.

Comment: @eyllanesc, I understand your point, but I respectfully disagree. I know Qt's widgets well enough that I could write a two-paragraph summary describing what C++ snippets from the documentation tend to leave out, and explain what a user generally needs to provide to turn them into working code. But I don't know QML very well, so I'm asking here for somebody else to provide that information. I firmly believe that my question, as stated, _is_ answerable.  However, I'll accept an answer to the _specific_ question of how to run the QML snippet posted in my question, if that helps.

Comment: please change or improve the question, I have published a response that solves the particular problem and gives advice on how to correct future errors. You understand and execute the examples of the QtWidgets documentation because you know its logic, and you must do the same and learn from QML.

Comment: @ellyanesc, thanks, I totally see what you mean now. I'll clean this up and make the question about the state machine example, specifically. And I'll accept your answer in a few moments, after I've gotten it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation assumes some basic knowledge of the previous topics and in the initial paragraph: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-index.html gives you a list of topics that you should read and learn.

And like all language one must read the errors of the code and analyze its logic.

```
...main.qml:17:13: QML StateMachine: No initial state set for StateMachine
QStateMachine::start: No initial state set for machine. Refusing to start.
.../main.qml:19: ReferenceError: state is not defined
```

This error clearly indicates that the initial state is not recognized, and this can be caused by 2 reasons, the first is that you have not established it or the second is that you have established an inappropriate state, and in your case it is the second reason.

you have established the initial state:

```
initialState: state
```

but state does not exist, I think you wanted to place state1

```
initialState: state1
```

The button is not shown because you have established that its size is the same as that of the parent: `anchors.fill: parent`, and `Button`'s parent is `Rectangle`, and if `Rectangle` is not set a size will have a size of 0, causing the son to have it too. A possible solution is to establish Rectangle the size of the parent:

```
import QtQuick 2.8                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQml.StateMachine 1.0 as DSM

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Rectangle {
        anchors.fill: parent
        Button {
            anchors.fill: parent
            id: button
            text: "Finish state"
            DSM.StateMachine {
                id: stateMachine
                initialState: state1
                running: true
                DSM.State {
                    id: state1
                    DSM.SignalTransition {
                        targetState: finalState
                        signal: button.clicked
                    }
                }
                DSM.FinalState {
                    id: finalState
                }
                onFinished: Qt.quit()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

or not use Rectangle:

```
import QtQuick 2.8                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQml.StateMachine 1.0 as DSM

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Button {
        anchors.fill: parent
        id: button
        text: "Finish state"
        DSM.StateMachine {
            id: stateMachine
            initialState: state1
            running: true
            DSM.State {
                id: state1
                DSM.SignalTransition {
                    targetState: finalState
                    signal: button.clicked
                }
            }
            DSM.FinalState {
                id: finalState
            }
            onFinished: Qt.quit()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me figure this out, I'm now able to start playing around with the declarative FSM framework! (I wound up taking your advice of _not_ using the `Rectangle` component.) For anybody else coming across this question, I recommend skipping the simple example I copied from the Qt docs and going straight to [this one](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmlstatemachine.html#a-simple-state-machine), because it's easier to see what's going on. (The first example simply _exits_ when you click the button, so it's a less compelling demonstration of what the framework can do.)